# Search across all Rally workspace object types

Tags: rally

I'm trying to figure out how to construct a JavaScript query that searches a Rally workspace for any and all objects of any type that in any field contain a specified string (prefix, infix or suffix).

I'm aware that https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/search?keywords=US1234 provides this capability, but I want the invocation to return JSON, so I can manipulate the resultant data.

All of the Rally search API approaches I've seen allow for searching on a single object type or a single field. Is there an "omni-search" method?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing is probably the artifact endpoint.  This will allow you to search any of the artifact types.  You can include a search parameter here as well, which should return very similar results as the search endpoint.  Just make sure you also include a types parameter to specify which work item types to include in the results:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/artifact?types=defect,hierarchicalrequirement&search=foo

Comment: Not sure how I missed artifact search, but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks, Kyle.

Comment: Just FYI: If you include "portfolioitem" in the types list, it doesn't return all portfolio items - you need to specify the exact type, for eg. "portfolioitem/feature".